# Replacing null based on a condition

Tags: sql, oracle, join, select, left-join

I am having a table with many columns (but posting only col1, col2, col3 here for simplified post):

```
id    col1       col2            col3    source_id
a1    765.3      23-Apr-08       cat     a5
a2    3298.3     (null)          dog     a4
a3    8762.1     27-Nov-10       rat     a8
a4    (null)     (null)          (null) (null)      
a5    (null)     (null)          (null)  a6
a6    (null)     (null)          (null)  (null)
```

I want to fill `null values of source _id` with `values from id`.
For example, `source_id a5 row has null` which has to replaced with `id a1 values`, subsequently, `source_id a6 row having null` to be replaced with `a5 row`

Output:

```
id    col1       col2            col3   source_id
a1    765.3      23-Apr-08       cat    a5
a2    3298.3     (null)          dog    a4
a3    8762.1     27-Nov-10       rat    a8
a4    3298.3     (null)          dog   (null)       
a5    765.3      23-Apr-08       cat    a6
a6    765.3      23-Apr-08       cat  (null)
```

Comment: How to identify which value is to be replaced?

Comment: All the values to be replaced @JimMacaulay, thanks!

Comment: For example, source_id a5 row has null which has to replaced with id a1 values, subsequently, source_id a6 row having null to be replaced with a5 row. In this how to identify if i have to replace with a1 or a2 or others?

Comment: `source id a5` to be replaced with `id a1`, because row containing `source id a5` has `id value a1` and `a4 to be replaced with a2` in same pattern @JimMacaulay

Comment: What is that patters? why source id a5 should be replaced with id value a1?

Comment: Every source_id to be replaced with corresponding id row value @JimMacaulay

Comment: @omdurg . . . I don't get it.  The last row has values from rows a1, a3, and a1 and no indication of why.

Comment: Sorry, was typo, fixed it @GordonLinoff, thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a `left join` and conditional logic:

```
select 
    t.id,
    coalesce(t.col1, t1.col1) col1,
    coalesce(t.col2, t1.col2) col2,
    coalesce(t.col3, t1.col3) col3,
    t.source_id
from mytable t
left join mytable t1 on t1.id = t.source_id
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @GMB, would I be able to modify this for cases where `source_id` has more than one match in `id`. For example, if both `id a1 and a2` have same `source_id a5`

Comment: @omdurg: the query should work equally well in the use case that you are describing.

Comment: If there is more than one match, I would like to sum up values in each match (except the date column, it can be ignored) @GMB, so for summing up values, what could I use to sum()

Comment: Could I edit the table here for this scenario @GMB, or post as a new one