# Conditional NULL replacement

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having a table with many columns:(previous post had just one id per one source_id, but this case has more than one id per one source_id)

```
id    col1             source_id
a1    765.3            a5
a2    3298.3           a4
a3    8762.1           a8
a4    3298.3           (null)      
a5    (null)           a6
a6    (null)           (null)
a7    10               a5
```

I want to fill `null values of source _id` with `values from id`.
For example, `source_id a5 row has null` which has to replaced with `id a1 + id a7 values`, subsequently, `source_id a6 row having null` to be replaced with `a5 row`

Output:

```
id    col1             source_id
a1    765.3            a5
a2    3298.3           a4
a3    8762.1           a8
a4    3298.3           (null)      
a5    765.3+10=775.3   a6
a6    765.3+10=775.3   (null)
a7    10               a5
```

Thanks!!

**EDIT**:

To make it more clear, null values in columns other than source_id and id needs to be filled. Given only col1 for simplified post, there might be many columns as well

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: Could may be look into this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62061075/replacing-null-based-on-a-condition) @VBoka

Comment: Your description is very confusing to me.  You say you want to "fill null values of source_id", but your sample output still has null values in that column.  You say "source_id a5 row has null" but there is no row that has a source_id of a5 and a value of null in any other column, so I don't know what you mean.

Comment: Also, please don't use `code` to highlight arbitrary chunks of text.

Comment: You say : "I want to fill null values of source _id with values from id." and in the output you do not do that ?

Comment: Hope my edit clears it! @VBoka

Comment: Hi @omdurg , so none of the answers is ok ?

Answer (score 0):

The next select will give you those rows that have a reference in the source_id column and value in the col1 column.

```
select id 
       , case when col1 is null then
              (select sum(col1) from test tt where tt.sourceid = t.id)
         else
              col1
         end result
       , sourceid
from test t     
order by id;
```

[here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=646cc5bc043e5c761767c48071d7ef38)

This is an option for the complete solution:

```
with cte as (select t.id 
       , case when t.col1 is null then
              (select sum(tt.col1) from test tt where tt.sourceid = t.id)
         else
              t.col1
         end result
       , t.sourceid
from test t     
order by id)
select t.id 
       , 
          case when t.result is null then
              (select sum(tt.result) from cte tt where tt.sourceid = t.id)
         else
              t.result
         end result
       , t.sourceid
from cte t     
order by id
```

[here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=db51cd218718a85e93d33a3499cce3ca)

Answer (score 0):

Use a correlated hierarchical query (you can correlate on either the `id` column or the `ROWID` pseudo-column):

```sql
SELECT id,
       COALESCE(
         col1,
         (
           SELECT SUM( COALESCE( col1, 0 ) )
           FROM   table_name s
           START WITH s.ROWID = t.ROWID
           CONNECT BY source_id = PRIOR id
         )
       ) AS col1,
       source_id
FROM   table_name t;
```

So, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( id, col1, source_id ) AS
SELECT 'a1',  765.3, 'a5' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'a2', 3298.3, 'a4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'a3', 8762.1, 'a8' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'a4', 3298.3, null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'a5',   null, 'a6' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'a6',   null, null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'a7',     10, 'a5' FROM DUAL;
```

This outputs:

> ```
> ID |   COL1 | SOURCE_ID
> :- | -----: | :--------
> a1 |  765.3 | a5       
> a2 | 3298.3 | a4       
> a3 | 8762.1 | a8       
> a4 | 3298.3 | null     
> a5 |  775.3 | a6       
> a6 |  775.3 | null     
> a7 |     10 | a5
> ```

You might need to stop iterating through the when you find the first non-null value in each branch of the hierarchy. That would just require adding a simple filter:

```sql
SELECT id,
       COALESCE(
         col1,
         (
           SELECT SUM( COALESCE( col1, 0 ) )
           FROM   table_name s
           START WITH s.ROWID = t.ROWID
           CONNECT BY source_id = PRIOR id
                  AND PRIOR col1 IS NULL
         )
       ) AS col1,
       source_id
FROM   table_name t;
```

(The output is the same as above).

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d0c200df7895a504991df4d5d7190da9)*